# Manga where the main character is summoned by a king of a kingdom, then kicked out to live in a forest infested by an army of the demon

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai, demons

I forgot the description, but it's about the mc being summoned by a king of a kingdom, then kicked out to live in a forest infested by an army of the demon. He later purifies the whole Forest. I read this about a year ago, and the last time I checked, it had more than 10+ chapters, probably 15-30.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this manga, and who/what was the main character summoned by?

Comment: Ahh honestly I think about a year ago, the main character was summoned by a king of a kingdom

Comment: That extra bit of info helped me find what looks to be a perfect match. If my answer below is correct, please [upvote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it and mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if it's incorrect, please indicate that with a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: That's correct! Thanks alot for the help :D

Comment: In that case, please mark the answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It will reward me with some [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), and helps with the administration of the site. Also, please consider [upvoting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer as well, if you haven't already. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Might this be *[Lv2 kara Cheat datta Motoyuusha Kouho no Mattari Isekai Life / Chillin Different World Life of the Ex-Brave Candidate was Cheat from Lv2](https://myanimelist.net/manga/119152/Lv2_kara_Cheat_datta_Motoyuusha_Kouho_no_Mattari_Isekai_Life/pics)*?

[image]

> Banaza, who got summoned to the magic kingdom of Cryroad as a hero candidate, due to having only the abilities of only a regular citizen, got treated as a disqualified hero. He, who originally was supposed to be returned to his original world, due to the magic kingdom's mistake, was inevitably forced to live in this new world. That kind of person, the moment he became level 2 after defeating a single slime, acquired all sorts of skills, and transcended into a super cheat with all status abilities broken through the limit! Even so, he does things at his own pace with an easygoing smile.

The main character, Banaza, is summoned to the Kingdom of Cryroad as a "hero candidate", but upon being evaluated, it's determined that he has low stats and "no trace of God's power". He is subsequently rejected in favour of the next candidate to show up, who happens to have very high stats. Banaza then winds up in the Forest of Delavaza, where he unknowingly wipes out the first unit of a demon army using purification magic.

The series currently has 22 chapters.

[image]

[image]

[image]